# Does WebClient.DownloadDataAsync really throw exceptions itself?

Tags: c#, webclient

The [MSDN documentation for `WebClient.DownloadDataAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144191.aspx) lists two potential exceptions that may come from calling that method.

Exceptions:

- ArgumentNullException - The address parameter is null.
- WebException - The URI formed by combining BaseAddress and address is invalid. -or- An error occurred while downloading the resource.

While I don't doubt that those exceptions may occur at some point when this code is called, can they actually originate from that line of execution or will they only surface in the raised `DownloadDataCompleted` event's `e.Error` property?

In other words, would a `try`/`catch` around `WebClient.DownloadDataAsync` actually catch anything or are they just describing the errors that could show up in `e.Error`?

```
using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient()) {
    webClient.DownloadDataCompleted += (sender, e) => {
        if (e.Error != null) {
            // Exceptions definitely available here.
            Console.WriteLine(e.Error.Message);
        }
        else {
            Console.WriteLine("Success!");
        }
    };
    try {
        webClient.DownloadDataAsync(someUri);
    }
    catch {
        // Would this ever be hit?
        Console.WriteLine("Caught an exception from DownloadDataAsync.");
    }
}
```

I tried a simple 404 error and the catch block wasn't hit (while the `e.Errors` code was), but I didn't know if some other situation would throw from the download call itself.

Comment: What happened when you tried passing `null` or an invalid URI to DownloadDataAsync?

Comment: you could decompile `DownloadDataAsync` (for example  with Reflector) and find out whether it throws anything...

Comment: @dtb A `null` URI did indeed hit the `catch` block. Thank you. Now I guess I need to poke at ILSpy to see if I can find a `WebException` it can throw.

Comment: I think testing or using decompilers is not enough! This is just current behavior, not documented behavior.

Comment: I've already got my answer and will need to make sure I handle this situation. I was only going to decompile for my own confirmation. When I saw 400 and 500 errors only showing in `e.Error`, I figured that was going to be the point for all exceptions to surface.

Comment: If I remember correctly, DNS lookups are always performed synchronously, even if the HTTP request is performed asynchronously. So you might get a WebException from DownloadDataAsync if the DNS name cannot be found.

Comment: @usr, what do you mean "not documented" when it is specified on MSDN?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov if it is specified on MSDN then by all means post an answer. Knowledge derived from ILSpy or testing is not good enough though.

Comment: @dtb ILSpy indicated it could throw a `WebException` if the URI fails to combine the base address URI with the relative URI address. I have yet to find an example of this (still looking). It's making me think those exceptions can be completely mitigated with `Uri.TryCreate`.

Comment: [qualifying my last comment] You may be able to mitigate the exceptions with an _absolute_ URI from `Uri.TryCreate` since `WebClient` has its own [`BaseAddress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.baseaddress.aspx) it may use for the final URI.

Comment: @usr, I'm still not sure about your comment: question is "exceptions are specified in MSDN, but not sure if I *really* get one". Or your comment was about some other exception which I missed?

Comment: My point was that if MSDN says which exceptions are thrown but doesn't say if they appear immediately or in the task, then it is undocumented what happens. It is generally not a good thing to rely on undocumented behavior because it can change at any time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `DownloadDataAsync` will throw `ArgumentNullException` directly.  It will also throw `NotSupportedException` and `UriFormatException`.  But any `WebException`s will come through the callback (i.e. the event).

Comment: The reference source code at http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx